# InvalidOperationException thrown regarding DotNetOpenAuth.IEmbeddedResourceRetrieval with Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, dotnetopenauth

When my Razor view calls `@Html.OpenIdSelector(...` I get an `InvalidOperationException`:

> The current IHttpHandler is not one of
>   types: System.Web.UI.Page,
>   DotNetOpenAuth.IEmbeddedResourceRetrieval.
>   An embedded resource URL provider must
>   be set in your .config file.

What exactly should I set in the `config` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>Just [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) the `DotNetOpenAuth` package. It will setup everything you need in your config file:</strike>

[image]

1. Right click on the `References` of your web project in the solution explorer
2. `Add Library Package Reference...`
3. Click on the `Online` tab.
4. In the search box type `dotnetopenauth`
5. Click `Install`

Everything will be automatically setup and the correct assemblies will be downloaded from the internet and added as reference.

Here's how the `web.config` file looks like after performing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="uri" type="System.Configuration.UriSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <section name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <legacyHMACWarning enabled="0" />
  </runtime>
  <uri>
    <!-- The uri section is necessary to turn on .NET 3.5 support for IDN (international domain names),
         which is necessary for OpenID urls with unicode characters in the domain/host name. 
         It is also required to put the Uri class into RFC 3986 escaping mode, which OpenID and OAuth require. -->
    <idn enabled="All" />
    <iriParsing enabled="true" />
  </uri>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" />
    <settings>
      <!-- This setting causes .NET to check certificate revocation lists (CRL) 
                 before trusting HTTPS certificates.  But this setting tends to not 
                 be allowed in shared hosting environments. -->
      <!--<servicePointManager checkCertificateRevocationList="true"/>-->
    </settings>
  </system.net>
  <dotNetOpenAuth>
    <!-- This is an optional configuration section where aspects of dotnetopenauth can be customized. -->
    <!-- For a complete set of configuration options see http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/configuration-options/ -->
    <openid>
      <relyingParty>
        <security requireSsl="false" />
        <behaviors>
          <!-- The following OPTIONAL behavior allows RPs to use SREG only, but be compatible
                         with OPs that use Attribute Exchange (in various formats). -->
          <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth" />
        </behaviors>
      </relyingParty>
    </openid>
    <messaging>
      <untrustedWebRequest>
        <whitelistHosts>
          <!-- Uncomment to enable communication with localhost (should generally not activate in production!) -->
          <!--<add name="localhost" />-->
        </whitelistHosts>
      </untrustedWebRequest>
    </messaging>
    <!-- Allow DotNetOpenAuth to publish usage statistics to library authors to improve the library. -->
    <reporting enabled="true" />
  </dotNetOpenAuth>
</configuration>
```

UPDATE:

You could implement a custom resource retrieval provider:

```
public class CustomResourceProvider : IEmbeddedResourceRetrieval
{
    public Uri GetWebResourceUrl(Type someTypeInResourceAssembly, string manifestResourceName)
    {
        return new Uri("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

and then register it in `web.config`:

```
<dotNetOpenAuth>
    <webResourceUrlProvider type="AppName.CustomResourceProvider, AppName" />
    ...
</dotNetOpenAuth>
```

But I would recommend you using the [openid-selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) library for generating login forms.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I've created the Custom Resource Provider and added the registration in the web.config but the issue still occurs.

Answer (score 8):

I came across this problem when I was trying to get the NerdDinner OpenID working for MVC3/razor. The solution that has worked for me is:

Create this class in your solution: (this was found in one of the NerdDinner builds - http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/55257#1328982 (thanks to JasonHaley)
for some reason, this file isn't in the latest build for NerdDinner MVC3/Razor

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DotNetOpenAuth;
namespace <Your App>.Services
{
    public class EmbeddedResourceUrlService : IEmbeddedResourceRetrieval
    {

        private static string pathFormat = "{0}/{1}/Resource/GetWebResourceUrl?assemblyName={2}&typeName={3}&resourceName={‌​4}";
        //private static string pathFormat = "{0}/Resource/GetWebResourceUrl";

        public Uri GetWebResourceUrl(Type someTypeInResourceAssembly, string manifestResourceName)
        {
            if (manifestResourceName.Contains("http"))
            {
                return new Uri(manifestResourceName);
            }
            else
            {
                var assembly = someTypeInResourceAssembly.Assembly;

                // HACK
                string completeUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
                string host = completeUrl.Substring(0,
                    completeUrl.IndexOf(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath));

                var path = string.Format(pathFormat,
                            host,
                            HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath.Substring(1),
                            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(assembly.FullName),
                            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(someTypeInResourceAssembly.ToString()),
                            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(manifestResourceName));

                return new Uri(path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your web.config, add this line:

```
<webResourceUrlProvider type="<Your App>.Services.EmbeddedResourceUrlService, <Your App>" />
```

just put in the DotNetOpenAuth section

you will also need this route set up: ( [Html.OpenIdSelectorScripts helper method throwing NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138534/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object) )

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "OpenIdDiscover",
        "Auth/Discover"
    );
```

Comment: NOTE: the formation of the URI will not work for application in their own folder under the root (and it might be a bit challenging for some to diagnose).

Comment: Use this for the path string:         private static string pathFormat = "{0}/{1}/Resource/GetWebResourceUrl?assemblyName={2}&typeName={3}&resourceName={4}";

Comment: and this to populate it:                  var path = string.Format(pathFormat,
                            host,
                            HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath.Substring(1),
                            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(assembly.FullName),
                            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(someTypeInResourceAssembly.ToString()),
                            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(manifestResourceName));

Comment: Otherwise DotNetOpenAuth will generate http://hostname/Resource/GetWebResourceUrl... instead of http://hostname/apppath/Resource/GetWebResourceUrl...

Comment: @BCooksey, I've applied your comments to the answer.  Thanks.