# dynamic error in asp.net mvc 3.0 razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to add some code that I got from nerdinner

```
  @Html.OpenIdSelector(this.Page, new SelectorButton[] 
     {
        new SelectorProviderButton("https://me.yahoo.com/", Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/Index/yahoo_64.png")),
        new SelectorProviderButton("https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id", Url.Content("~/Content/images/google.gif")),
        new SelectorOpenIdButton(Url.Content("~/Content/images/openid.gif")),
    })
```

however I get this error

> Error 1   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
>   has no applicable method named
>   'OpenIdSelector' but appears to have
>   an extension method by that name.
>   Extension methods cannot be
>   dynamically dispatched. Consider
>   casting the dynamic arguments or
>   calling the extension method without
>   the extension method syntax.

I have no clue what it wants.

**Edit**

I get this now

> CS1928:
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'OpenIdSelector' and the best
>   extension method overload
>   'DotNetOpenAuth.Mvc.OpenIdHelper.OpenIdSelector(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   params
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.SelectorButton[])'
>   has some invalid arguments

**Edit 2**

They must have changed it. I was checking and my version of dotnetopenauth does not take in 2 parameters only 1.

Nerd dinners version takes in 2.

Anyways now I removed that and get this

> Server Error in '/' Application. The
>   current IHttpHandler is not one of
>   types: System.Web.UI.Page,
>   DotNetOpenAuth.IEmbeddedResourceRetrieval.
>   An embedded resource URL provider must
>   be set in your .config file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OpenIdSelector` is defined as an extension method and you don't have to pass in the first parameter. Instead you call it like this:

```
@Html.OpenIdSelector(new SelectorButton[] {...})
```

This is equivalent to the following call:

```
@OpenIdHelper.OpenIdSelector(this.Html, new SelectorButton[] {...})
```

For the second Edit to your question, looks like this might help: [InvalidOperationException thrown regarding DotNetOpenAuth.IEmbeddedResourceRetrieval with Razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757291/dotnetopenauth-3-4-6-with-mvc3-invalidoperationexception)

Answer (score 1):

The `Page` property is dynamic, and as such the `OpenIdSelector` method can't be despatched with a dynamic property. Try casting the `Page` property:

```
@Html.OpenIdSelector((Page)this.Page, new SelectorButton[] { ... });
```

Comment: Having never used the `OpenIdSelector` method I can't say I'm familiar with it. Does it have a second (first through extension syntax) parameter that is of `Page` type?